# For anyone who has a "Keter" Perf-Tzit t-shirt style arba kanfos, can it be put in the washing machine without messing up the tzitzis?

Tags: tzitzis

For anyone who has a "Keter" Perf-Tzit t-shirt style arba kanfos, can it be put in the washing machine without messing up and/or unraveling the tzitzis?  I thought it said washing-machine safe on the package but I don't remember now.  If anyone has the package handy can they please screenshot it?

Answer (score 1):

Best to wash it separately with hand or delicate wash setting on the machine. When finished, take out and separate the Tzitzit by hand  and hang to dry. Avoid using the dryer. Works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

So if you look on this website [here](https://www.judaicaplace.com/perf-tzit-undershirt-tzitzis-keter-v-neck-size-18-ashkenazi-meyuchad-6-pack/ptka18v6pk/) which stocks and sells this brand. It includes washing instructions in the description.

It writes:

> *Wash in lukewarm water on a gentle cycle. Use Tziztis Wash Bags to prevent tangling of strings.*